# Using other than python files in a python package

Tags: python, package

I have the following file structure in my python project.
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W6IN.png)

As you can see in the file structure, the SuperMarket is a python package which I made.
The problem is that I am unable to use any of the text files inside the datafiles directory in any of the python files inside the package.For example,
The following is a code snippet in inside the brands.py

```
class Brands:
    def getBrandsData(self, b_id=False, name=False):
        """:returns a list containing all brand data based on parameters"""
        data = []
        with open('dataFiles/brands.txt', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
            for row in reader:
                subData = []
                if b_id:
                    subData.append(row[0])
                if name:
                    subData.append(row[1])
                data.append(subData)
        if [b_id, name].count(True) == 1:
            data = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
        return data
```

When i call the function from main.py I get the following runtime error.

```
with open('dataFiles/brands.txt', 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataFiles/brands.txt'
```

What modification can I make on my program to overcome this problem.
I am new to this kind of python packages.Can someone help me to come out of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i worked with many tries, I got this feasible answer.
What I understood is that even if we are creating a package with other than python files, we should specify the path realative to the root folder. So in my prblem the modified code snippet is

```
class Brands:
    def getBrandsData(self, b_id=False, name=False):
        """:returns a list containing all brand data based on parameters"""
        data = []
        with open("SuperMarket/dataFiles/brands.txt", 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
            for row in reader:
                subData = []
                if b_id:
                    subData.append(row[0])
                if name:
                    subData.append(row[1])
                data.append(subData)
        if [b_id, name].count(True) == 1:
            data = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
class Brands:
    def getBrandsData(self, b_id=False, name=False):
        """:returns a list containing all brand data based on parameters"""
        data = []
        with open("/dataFiles/brands.txt", 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
            for row in reader:
                subData = []
                if b_id:
                    subData.append(row[0])
                if name:
                    subData.append(row[1])
                data.append(subData)
        if [b_id, name].count(True) == 1:
            data = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
        return data
```

I'm not exactly sure but I think it might work
*I don't have the correct file structure so I don't know, It's my best guess

Answer (score 0):

if your file is in current directory then simply use the file name in open() function.

if your file is in sub directory or any other directory then specified the full path of file
here is an example

f = open("brands.txt")    # open file in current directory

f = open("/full/path/to/brands.txt")  # specifying full path

Comment: Are you saying to use the absolute path other than Relative path?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the code, you can type.

```
import turtle
```

or whatever you want to insert
Look at this website to see all the packages: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_packages.php

Comment: turtle is a package for drawing graphics for kids.How you are saying it can help in this problem.

Comment: How can importing a graphics library help in this problem?